# Semantic-ui Accordion: control style of nested accordion

Tags: css, semantic-ui

I'm using the semantic-ui [accordion](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/accordion/) in my app; When using the styled option a bordered box is shown around each option and when I have too many elements its so confusing.

So I tried with styled={false} but then the indentation between different level was gone! I mean all levels are indented the same:

[image]

I tried to control it and make indentation by myself but didn't manage to do that!

The other option is to work with styled={true} and to override semantic css according to my needs (maybe to leave only the border-bottom and decrease the padding between elements):

[image]

I tired doing that by adding for example:

```
.ui.styled.accordion .accordion {
/*background-color: aliceblue;*/
/*border: 0;*/
outline: none;
}
```

But didnt manage to git red of the border yet. Any ideas?

Comment: Hey, try to apply below css:
.ui.accordion .accordion {
    box-shadow: none !important;
}
If you are looking to remove border then you will achieve it by this css.

Comment: Great thanks. Any idea how to reduce the space between elements? is it padding in  .ui.accordion .accordion .content?

Comment: Manage padding top for below class as per your requirement.
.ui.styled.accordion .accordion .content{padding-top: 0;}